# Python import module from non-installed package

Tags: python, python-import, git-submodules

For my project i want to use external libraries, connected to git repository as submodules. They are located in `shared-lib` folder, that is added to `sys.path`.
All libraries contains `setup.py` file and subfolder with python module. How can i import that module without installing whole package and without changing it structure?

`import module_name.module_name` does not work, i get `No module named module_name.module_name` because there is no `__init__.py` file inside module_name directory.

My project does not require installation, because it is plugin for another system. So i can use only python import.

Comment: I think the proper way to set `sys.path` is to point to the distribution packages *top-level* directory where `__init__.py` is there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html).

```
import imp

foo = imp.load_source('module1.foo', 'module1/module1/foo.py')
bar = imp.load_source('module2.bar', 'module2/module2/bar.py')

print(foo)
print(bar)
```

Output:

```
<module 'module1.foo' from 'module1/module1/foo.py'>
<module 'module2.bar' from 'module2/module2/bar.py'>
```

Comment: In this case i'll need to load multiple files per package. Maybe i can do something with pkg_resources?